# How to create Sub directory in Cpanel and main site open mobile redirect mobile site?

Tags: php, yii, ftp, cpanel

How to create subdirectory in cpanel and after how to redirect mobile site open in mobile.
example subdirectory: www.XYZ.com to test.XYZ.com .

Comment: Create folder name **test** in subdirectory. then point to test.xyz.com.  Path should be **rootdirectory/test**. This **[link](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/SubDomains)** will help you

Comment: i have already crate but this work on www.xyz.com/test i want test.xyz.com please help

Comment: who is the hosting provider?

Comment: how to redirect mobile site open in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Write below code in `index.php` file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 800) {                // change as per req.
    window.location = "http://test.XYZ.com";
  }
  //-->
</script>
```

This is old method.

Now days, Responsive web design (RWD) is a web design approach aimed at crafting sites to provide an optimal viewing experience—easy reading and navigation with a minimum of resizing, panning, and scrolling—across a wide range of devices (from mobile phones to desktop computer monitors)

Comment: Sorry , but my site create in YII framwork please help where input code

Comment: I am not userfriendly with yll. In index file of test folder http://hostname/test/index.php